# Ruby Mock a File and Check Contents

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am writing a gem which adds dependencies to a gemfile from the command line. Given the gem name, it grabs the latest version from rubygems and adds it to the user's gemfile.

I practice test driven development using `rspec`. I'm wondering how do I mock the existence of a file and check it's contents?

Is there any pattern for doing this sort of thing? Tips, links or examples will help. I'm not set on a specific way of testing this. If mocking isn't the way to go, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock a file object that only needs to be written and read from (no filesystem operations), try Ruby's builtin `StringIO`. Just `require 'stringio'`, create a 'file' with any contents by using `StringIO.new("Some contents")`, and check its contents by using the `string` method on the StringIO object.

Answer (score 0):

### Unit Tests vs. Integration Tests

You didn't post any code, so I'm going to have to make some assumptions. In general, exercising behavior from Ruby's core or standard libraries is a waste of time. In addition, your tests should exercise methods that define class behavior, not necessarily every single method in a class.

When you cross the boundary to testing I/O, you're often doing integration tests. Sometimes integration tests are necessary, but they should make a very small subset when compared to unit tests.

With all that said, while integration tests that involve filesystem, database, or network I/O are often slower than unit tests, whether or not they are *slow enough* to warrant stubbing, mocking, or test-specific work-arounds will be specific to your code base.

### Options for Testing

If you really need to do this, you have a lot of options. Some of these options include:

1. Using a RAM disk for your filesystem I/O.
2. Stubbing calls to IO, File, or FileUtils.
3. Avoiding the issue by using a file fixture.
4. Avoiding the issue by using a StringIO fixture.
5. Re-writing your class under test to accept String and/or StringIO in addition to File objects.
6. Using a gem like [FakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) to handle the stubbing/mocking for you.

This isn't meant to be an canonically exhaustive list. There are doubtless other options, but one or more of the above should handle any common use case.